# Need to get the string from a variable which contains the path

Tags: linux

I am working on log archival script.

I have three directories in a machine

```
  /opt/tibco/run/tibbpma/tibcohost/BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01/host/logs
  /opt/tibco/run/tibbpmb/tibcohost/BPM_DEV_TIBBPMB_HOST_01/host/logs
  /opt/tibco/run/tibbpmc/tibcohost/BPM_DEV_TIBBPMC_HOST_01/host/logs
```

script goes to each directory with for loop and find all the logs with pattern *.log.* and move the files with date appended to a common directory under `/opt/tibco/scripts/logs/archive`

log names under 3 `/opt/tibco/run/*/*/*/logs` directories sometimes same and being   overwritten with one another when moved. so to avoid overwrite, I would like add     `tibbpma_BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01_` to the file name to have the distinct file name.

please help us to get the `tibbpma_BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01_` or `tibbpmb_BPM_DEV_TIBBPMB_HOST_01_` or `tibbpmc_BPM_DEV_TIBBPMC_HOST_01_`

Comment: my script should be generic and should handle any directory irrespective of environment. the directories may be different in other server like /opt/tibco/run/tibbpma/tibcohost/BPM_ITG_TIBBPMA_HOST_01/host/logs
  /opt/tibco/run/tibbpmb/tibcohost/BPM_ITG_TIBBPMB_HOST_01/host/logs
  /opt/tibco/run/tibbpmc/tibcohost/BPM_ITG_TIBBPMC_HOST_01/host/logs      /opt/tibco/run/tibbpma/tibcohost/BPM_STG_TIBBPMA_HOST_01/host/logs
  /opt/tibco/run/tibbpmb/tibcohost/BPM_STG_TIBBPMB_HOST_01/host/logs
  /opt/tibco/run/tibbpmc/tibcohost/BPM_STG_TIBBPMC_HOST_01/host/logs. these paths are differ with diffe machine

Comment: is it possible to search with string tibbpm, if it exists, get the 4th and 6th strings that are separated by /

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `grep -o -P 'BPM[^/]+'` to extract desired parts from those paths, for example

```
$ echo /opt/tibco/run/tibbpma/tibcohost/BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01/host/logs | grep -o -P 'BPM[^/]+' 
BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression:

```
\/opt\/tibco\/run\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/host\/logs
```

For   /opt/tibco/run/tibbpma/tibcohost/BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01/host/logs

```
$1 would return tibbpma
$2 would return tibcohost
$3 would return BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01
```

You can then make your desired string using $1, $2 and $3

Sample perl code to give the string you are looking for

```
my $str = "/opt/tibco/run/tibbpma/tibcohost/BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01/host/logs";
if ($str =~ /\/opt\/tibco\/run\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/host\/logs/) {
        print $1 . "_" . $2 . "_". $3;
}
```

Give output as tibbpma_tibcohost_BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01
If you want to omit , tibcohost part .. either omit $2 from the regular expression above

OR

use the RE /opt/tibco/run/([^/]*)/[^/]*/([^/]*)/host/logs

```
my $str = "/opt/tibco/run/tibbpma/tibcohost/BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01/host/logs";
if ($str =~ /\/opt\/tibco\/run\/([^\/]*)\/[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)\/host\/logs/) {
        print $1 . "_" . $2 ;
}
```

to get tibbpma_BPM_DEV_TIBBPMA_HOST_01